# Как установить Delphi XE в 2024 году?

Tags: delphi-xe

Как установить Delphi XE в 2024 году в России? Как обойти выключение серверов?
Ошибка при установке: "Tray to resume the broken downloads".
Кто как справился с проблемой?
*(нужен только из-за старых проектов с встроенным RaveReport)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Загугли портабл версию. Они существуют